# Connecting an Ultra ATA 3.5 HDD to a laptop

Tags: connection

What do I need to connect an Ultra Ata 3.5" HDD to my laptop? The HDD is a Seagate DB35.2 160 Gbytes to connect to a Dell Inspiron 17 5000.
Mac

Comment: Thanks. Would the Vantec CB-ISATAU2 SATA/IDE to USB 2.0 Adapter suit the purpose. Yes my name is Mac - it's a Win 8 system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your laptop is newer than your drive, you would need a PATA to SATA or USB adaptor, depending on whether you wish to mount it internally or externally.

[I'd recommend to USB & mount externally - enclosure is optional, converter is essential]

Google has a lot of choices - https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=pata+to+usb+converter&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

<sup>I'm also assuming you mean to a Windows PC & just coincidentally your name is Mac, not your computer</sup>